# how does this fastening system work

Tags: bearings, fasteners

the bearing in the pictures below is securely fastened with some kind of rivet that doesn't take up any room on either side, so that the bearing can roll through some tight spaces while still bearing very high loads. pun intended. how is the fastener applied? is there a hand tool that can be used? or would it require some kind of hydraulic press? the high load capacity is important here, as well as the low profile.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The image you show of the inner side is a bit dark its hard to see. But to be honest it looks to me like a [rivnut](https://www.rivetnutusa.com/rivnut-rivet-nut/) which indeed only needs a hand tool.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the rivet type piece is one and the same with the center piece of the bearing. It is made to fit through the hole and then deformed into place with a tool to secure it. Almost certainly not a hand tool I would say, but it could be pneumatic, hydraulic, or electric.